# How to use #pragma pack(1) OR /Zp1 so that these affect the packing of application-defined structures alone, not the ones defined in Windows SDK?

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi, compilation, pragma

I'm porting my application (a mixture of win32 and MFC) compiled using VC98 (built using makefiles on command line, NOT IDE)(x86) to Visual Studio 2017 (x64).
The application uses a huge number of C structs and these are packed with data, copied onto a buffer and sent over the N/W.
The communication protocol requires these structures to have no extra padding at all so that the sent data conforms to the specifications used for communication b/w the client (my application) and the server.
To ensure this, the application uses /Zp for compiling each and every file.

After porting to VS2017 (x64) using /Zp (from IDE), when I tried to run the application, the application GUI does not start and I get exceptions from within the SDK and MFC when some SDK/MFC defined structs are accessed by the application, eg OPENFILENAME.
So,to solve this, with /Zp still defined at the project level in VS2017, I used the following where we include windows.h:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
#pragma pack(push,8)
#endif
#include <windows.h>
#ifdef _WIN64
#pragma pack(pop)
#endif
```

This solved the problem to some extent but I still get some errors from MFC and some features like crypt API (MSCAPI) don't work perhaps because there are other header files like windows.h included by my application that also need to be guarded like above.

As an alternative, I've also tried not using /Zp at all and then going to each and every header file and enclosing the entire contents of the file (after the system header file inclusions) between #pragma pack(1) and #pragma pack().
This works but is not foolproof and way too tedious for me to do the same thing for 1000's of header files.

So, in short, I need a way to ensure that all C structs defined by my application don't use any padding but those defined by Windows SDK/MFC continue to use the default padding (perhaps 8 bytes).
Any ideas as to how I can resolve this in a foolproof manner with minimum amount of changes?
Perhaps, this problem does not arise in VC98 either because the platform is x86 OR the SDK included with VC98 does not make any assumptions about the packing of structs.

Comment: Have you found your answer? Because pack(push, 8) is what I'm stuck with myself.

Is there a better way to undo /Zp1, so a code region is aligned to defaults and not explicitly to 8?

Comment: No I did not and I had to take the long, tedious nand error-prone route of ensuring the packing was disabled in my own header files but not in the SDK ones as I stated in the question, which is,
"As an alternative, I've also tried not using /Zp at all and then going to each and every header file and enclosing the entire contents of the file (after the system header file inclusions) between #pragma pack(1) and #pragma pack(). This works but is not foolproof and way too tedious for me to do the same thing for 1000's of header files."

Comment: see here for an explanation by Microsoft:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/64-bit-builds-may-not-work-if-packing-changed/194354#T-N240311-N240328-N241270

Comment: and this rule for SDK usage:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=18493

Answer (score 1):

Transmitting binary structure data over the network, or via files, is a very brittle approach:

- packing the structures only solves the alignment issues so long as the types used int the `struct` definitions keep the same representation. Check the definitions of the low-level types used in your structures: `LONG` is still 32-bit on 64-bit Windows (!) but `size_t` has a different size.
- The byte ordering may differ across different machines: x86 uses little-endian representation, whereas some other processors used in cell phones or tablets may use big-endian. There is no way to force a specific byte ordering in memory.
- forcing structure member misalignment may cause undefined behavior on some processors, x86 is configured by default to be very lenient, this is usually not possible on other processors.
- in spite of being a very thin abstraction on top of the hardware, the C language does not allow precise control over the actual layout used for structures in memory. A good example of non portable mappings is the implementation of bitfields. Your structures might have bitfields that are mapped differently on 32-bit Windows and 64-bit architectures.

To solve these portability problems, modern programs do not rely on the internal representation of binary data, they handle structured data one member at a time to use the specific representation, size, byte ordering, bit encoding on both ends.

Comment: I know of the potential problems with serializing structs into a byte stream by relying on disabled padding. But as i said in the question, I have no other way since the application to be ported to x64 is a legacy one with millions of lines of code. As a result, tampering with the parsing logic is even more risky. So, I'd like to know a way to disable the padding for application-defined structures alone - not for the SDK ones.

Comment: I'm afraid porting a legacy application from 32-bit to 64-bit is not as simple as disabling the padding in API structures. Some of these structures might have a different layout between 32-bit and 64-bit platforms even with padding disabled. For example if any of these structures have a member with type `size_t`, the size will differ. I agree you definitely do not want the fiddle with the SDK structures layout, but if any of these are embedded in your application's own data structures, again the layout will differ.